# How do you specify the shebang line of a command script created by setuptools

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools

I have created a package that I will be distributing throughout the company that replaces a legacy bash script with the same name. It is referenced many places so it needs to execute like the current script does. This has worked fine until I encountered some servers that do not have a current version of Python as the default Python (aka CentOS).

Is there a way to specify in the setup.py what shebang line is created at the top of the script file? i.e. I need `#!/opt/bin/python` rather than `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question was answered by [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521034/keith). Running the setup.py as `/opt/bin/python setup.py install` produces the results I need without any user intervention.

Answer (score 1):

- Run the script with `/opt/bin/python script.py`, or
- edit the first line to read `#!/opt/bin/python`, or
- put `/opt/bin` in your path before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: While opt/bin is in my path, I can't guarantee that all users of the script will. The script will be installed on many machines so manual intervention is not an option. Users will be pip installing it from our own PyPi server.

Comment: @zenweasel setuptools will rewrite the shebang line to match to location of the Python interpreter currently running it. So you you invoke the build as `/opt/bin/python setup.py ...` it will get that in the shebang line.

Comment: @Keith, thanks, that's the answer I needed. If you want to put in an answer I can mark it as THE answer. Especially as I have edited the questions, these other answers are not as applicable.

Comment: This answer does not try to understand the problem in any capacity. The question is about `setup.py build` and its arguments, and what is used to generate this line, not how to fix it manually after package is built.

Answer (score 0):

First understand why shebang is needed -
Using a shebang lets the system know which command to use to run the script.

What does that mean?
It means when you simply execute your script like this in the terminal -

```
$ ./script.py
```

"script.py" is given as an argument to the command you have mentioned in the commandline.

So, if the shebang points to the python interpreter, the above command would be equivalent to this -

```
$ python script.py
```

So now you can understand the purpose of shebang - It just gives the path of the script interpreter. (in your case, the python interpreter).

Note, that shebang is meaningless if you execute your script like this -

```
$ python script.py
```

(This is because you are calling the python executable and passing script.py as the first argument and it simply ignores the first line as it is a comment for it.)

So, coming to your problem now -
If you have two python installations and you want to execute your script using the non default python installation, what you do is either -
1. simply execute as `$ /opt/bin/python script.py` and ignore the shebang.
OR
2. Change `script.py`'s shebang you can and then you can execute as `./script.py`

I would choose the 1st option if I had to run `script.py` just once, and the 2nd one if I had to execute it many times (so I don't waste time writing `/opt/bin/python` every time)

Comment: Thanks, however that doesn't address my question at all. The question is getting setuptools to add the correct information since this script will be widely distributed in our company.

Comment: Look, it doesn't matter where the she bang points if you are executing it like this - `$ /opt/bin/python script.py`, so why care about setuptools adding the correct information? I think I have already answered your question. Still, you may clearify what exactly you want. (or atleast just tell me how do you propose to execute the script on your machines.)

Comment: Yes, that is all well understood.The scripts are going to be executed by php files, by cron jobs, by webservices, etc. It is replacing a bash script file with the exact same name that is executed by other shell scripts. So it needs to be executed exactly as `$scriptname`.

Comment: Sorry that I did not make the context of my question more clear, but it is strictly about setuptools, I didn't want to bore everybody with the whole backstory on why I need it.

Comment: “She bang is required so that your python script can be interpreted as a bash script.” This has nothing to do with Bash, using a shebang let the system know which command to use to run the script.

Comment: @bfontaine Thanks. I think I had a wrong understanding at the time I wrote the answer & did not bother to correct it lateron.